How to show files already loaded in filepond (for ex. edit page)
I already read other similar questions but didn't find any solution in this case.
I'm using filepond in a laravel project. I can upload images, but in my model's edit page I can't show images already loaded. They are stored on an amazon s3 bucket, with public read access (already verified direct browser access).
I'm using the filepond's 'file' property, and passing data like this:
// [amazon server obscured for the case]
[
  {
    "source": "https://[amazon server].amazonaws.com/images/bosYPmxcSO3OzcRn1GJqaXJlC4lBZJ2KDmp8f7oC.png",
    "options": {
      "type": "local"
    }
  }
]

It's not clear to me what else I should do. Filepond docs do not have a lot of working examples.

Answering by myself. I needed to also add a load prop in the server prop:
load: (source, load) => {
  fetch(source).then(res => res.blob()).then(load);
},

So you'll have:
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
  acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],

  server: {
    process: // do things or pass route
    revert: // do things or pass route
    load: (source, load) => {
      fetch(source).then(res => res.blob()).then(load);
    },
  },

  files: [ // put whatever array
    {
      "source": "https://[amazon server].amazonaws.com/images/XJlC4lBZJ2KDmp8f7oC.png",
      "options": { "type": "local" }
    }
  ]
);

